# How to use hsc2hs to bind to constants, functions and data structures?

Tags: haskell, ffi, hsc2hs

i need a example how to use hsc2hs, i thought that when i write a header file like:

```
// foo.h
#define PI 3.14159

typedef struct {
    int i1;
    int i2;
} foo;

struct foo2 {
    int i1;
    int i2;
};

int fooFkt(foo f);
```

and then create a hsc file like:

```
import Foreign
import Foreign.C

#include "foo.h"
```

use `hsc2hs`:

```
{-# INCLUDE "foo.h" #-}
{-# LINE 1 "test.hsc" #-}
import Foreign
{-# LINE 2 "test.hsc" #-}
import Foreign.C


{-# LINE 5 "test.hsc" #-}
```

i dont understand it, i thought hat hsc2hs will import all needed things for me like the `PI`

who can give me a better example?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Following RWH [ch 17](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/interfacing-with-c-the-ffi.html#id654451), you need to introduce something that binds the C `PI` value to a symbol in Haskell.

For example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}
{-# LANGUAGE CPP                      #-}

import Foreign
import Foreign.C

-- helpers
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad

#include "foo.h"

-- binding a symbol

-- Note that hsc2hs can't marshal floating point CPP values, so this will be "3"
-- c_pi :: CInt
-- c_pi = #const PI

-- Instead, bind to a function that returns a CFloat
pi' :: Float
pi' = realToFrac c_pi

foreign import ccall unsafe "my_pi" c_pi :: CFloat
```

And while we're here, we can also marshal the struct to and from Haskell:

```
-- Marshalling for the struct foo

data Foo = Foo { i1, i2 :: Int }
    deriving Show

-- Define how to marshal foo structs

instance Storable Foo where
    sizeOf    _ = #{size foo}

    alignment _ = alignment (undefined :: CInt)

    poke p foo  = do
        #{poke foo, i1} p $ i1 foo
        #{poke foo, i2} p $ i2 foo

    peek p = return Foo
              `ap` (#{peek foo, i1} p)
              `ap` (#{peek foo, i2} p)
```

And bind to `fooFkt` function:

```
-- Import the function too

foreign import ccall "foo.h fooFkt"
    c_fooFkt :: Ptr Foo -> IO CInt

-- Marshal data to and from C

fooFkt :: Foo -> IO Int
fooFkt f = fromIntegral <$> with f c_fooFkt
```

Done.

Comment: Doesn't bindings-dsl provide some float constant #defines? #fractional or something like that?

Comment: bindings-dsl gives you that and a whole bunch of other really useful stuff. I highly recommend it: https://bitbucket.org/mauricio/bindings-dsl/wiki/DetailedUsageGuide

Answer (score 2):

It works if you actually use some definitions from `foo.h`:

```
import Foreign
import Foreign.C

#include "foo.h"

pi = #const PI
```

gives

```
{-# INCLUDE "foo.h" #-}
{-# LINE 1 "test.hsc" #-}
import Foreign
{-# LINE 2 "test.hsc" #-}
import Foreign.C


{-# LINE 5 "test.hsc" #-}

pi = 3
{-# LINE 7 "test.hsc" #-}
```

Here's a real world usage example from the network package: https://github.com/haskell/network/blob/master/Network/Socket/ByteString/MsgHdr.hsc

Comment: how can i do this with the structs?

Comment: pi = 3? Is this some float constant problem?

Comment: @aleator hsc2hs can only [marshal string and integer #defines](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.1/html/users_guide/hsc2hs.html).