# Using the Haskell FFI to marshal structs; also, how to use FunPtr

Tags: haskell, ffi

I have some questions about the ffi in `haskell`.

first of all i'm trying to work with c structs in `haskell`.

there i have some questions: i have a struct like

```
struct foo{int a; float b;};
```

1. when could i use `data Foo = Foo { a :: Int, b :: Float }  deriving (Show, Eq)`
2. when i have to implement a storable with peek and poke?

okay now a question about `FunPtr`

- i dont know when to use `FunPtr` why a normal definition like `Ptr CInt -> IO CInt` is not enough?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Marshalling*

To marshal structures, you *will* need to use a `Storable` class instance to marshal data back and forth, via `peek` and `poke`.

See this previous answer for an example: [How to use hsc2hs to bind to constants, functions and data structures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6056323/how-to-use-hsc2hs-to-bind-to-constants-functions-and-data-structures)

---

*FunPtr*

[`FunPtr`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.1/Foreign-Ptr.html#t:FunPtr) is only needed when you want to pass a function across the FFI boundary as a first-class value, *not* for calling foreign functions. Precisely:

> A value of type FunPtr a is a pointer to a function callable from foreign code. The type a will normally be a foreign type, a function type with zero or more arguments

An example, registering a call back function:

```
foreign import ccall "stdlib.h &free"
   p_free :: FunPtr (Ptr a -> IO ())
```

Since we have to pass `p_free` itself to a Haskell function, we have to let Haskell  know this is actually a C function. The `FunPtr` wrapper controls that.