# Haskell function that takes and returns a 'c' array

Tags: c, haskell, haskell-ffi

I'm looking for a complete working example of a Haskell FFI function that conceptually has signature: `ByteString -> ByteString`, i.e. which:

1. Takes as input an array of 8-bit unsigned integers which has been allocated on the 'c' heap (i.e. with a lifetime that exceeds the FFI invocation).
2. Transforms the array into a `ByteString` (assuming that `ByteString` can't feature directly in the FFI API).
3. Immutably transforms the `ByteString` in some manner (trivial example: reversing it).
4. Returns to the invoking 'c' function the transformed `ByteString` (or whatever FFI representation of it is required), such that it must be deleted on the 'c' side.

A Google search reveals a variety related and/or partial information, but the devil is very much in the details here: I haven't been able to find a relevant MWE (of what one would consider an elementary FFI application) anywhere.

EDIT: One commenter has kindly pointed out that ByteString already encapsulates a pointer and a length.

That leads to some more concrete questions:

**Q1.** What should the corresponding 'c' function signature for
`ByteString -> ByteString` be?

e.g. is it necessary to explicitly define ByteString on the 'c' side?

```
struct ByteString { uint8 * array; size_t length }; 
ByteString cfunc(ByteString arg);
```

It doesn't look like translating this directly yields a valid FFI call. For:

```
foreign export ccall cfunc ::  ByteString -> ByteString
```

the compiler error is "ByteString cannot be marshalled in foreign call".

**Q2** Does arg have to be somehow converted to a ByteString on the Haskell side or does the fact that it's (intended to be) structurally isomorphic suffice?

Comment: What is the question? What have you tried? What are you stuck on?

Comment: ByteString already is a "'c' array", as you call it. Except it is also stores the length of the array. You can see here https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.11.1.0/docs/src/Data.ByteString.Internal.html#ByteString. `ForeignPtr Word8` is the pointer to the array.

Comment: You can also find several examples of FFI usage https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.11.1.0/docs/src/Data.ByteString.Internal.html#c_strlen

Comment: @pedrofurla Thanks - that's useful to know. But it's still not clear what the corresponding 'c' function signature for ByteString -> ByteString would actually look like. Would it be something like:
struct ByteString { uint8 * array; size_t length }; ByteString cfunc(ByteString arg); or something else?
As I say in the question, there's no shortage of partial answers, but that still leaves a combinatorial explosion of possibilities in getting something actually working.

Comment: The signature you wrote is essentially correct. The compiler complains because your custom type needs a custom marshaller (particularly, a `Storable` instance). The FFI docs are pretty clear on this, see eg [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243815/using-the-haskell-ffi-to-marshal-structs-also-how-to-use-funptr). This also answers your 2nd question - your custom type does have to be converted, and it is precisely the Storable instance which does tge conversion.

Comment: BTW, I introduced myself into Haskell FFI by a mix of FFI docs, [language-c-inline](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/language-c-inline) which is a nice inlining tool for C code and example usages of this tool in [haskell-postal](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskell-postal).

Comment: @user2407038 Adding instance Storable ByteString still results in the same compiler error ...

Comment: @NietzscheanAI If you have a complete program, including an `instance Storable ByteString`, and it fails to compile, I suggest you include that full program in your question. Also on a second reading your type should be `Ptr ByteString -> Ptr ByteString`